# How to list the files details within a .7z file with a date parameter?

Tags: batch-file, command

For fetching the details within the .7z file without opening the file
I have used the below bat command. And it works like charm it lists down all the file within the multiple .7z files present under a given folder.

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s *.7z') do (7z.exe l -r "%%A" >> listing.txt)
```

However now I want to fetch date specific file so that it reads the .7z file based on the date modified and extracts the details accordingly.
Could someone let me know how to include the data parameter in the above command.

Sample 7z output:

```
   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2018-04-10 00:15:06 ....A       107026       249268  EAIObjMgr_enu_0045_47186365.log
2018-04-10 01:00:04 ....A       410085               EAIObjMgr_enu_0045_47186368.log
2018-04-10 01:35:03 ....A       390596               EAIObjMgr_enu_0045_47186371.log
2018-04-10 02:15:05 ....A       410086
```

Comment: An example of the 7zip output would probably help us answer your question.

Comment: `7z l` output is locale/user settings dependent, here each line starts with date time in this format `2018-04-10 19:00:47` so I simply had to append a `|find "2018-05-24"` to filter for todays files.

Comment: @LotPings Do we need to add the |find "2018-03-05" filter in the bat file script in the below way?
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s *.7z') do (7z.exe l -r "%%A" >> listing.txt) |find "2018-24-05"
I tried the above but it gave me the complete list of all the files present in the folder irrespective of the date mentioned above,i tried for different dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter for a given day `2018-03-05` use

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s *.7z') do (
  Echo Processing %%A >> listing.txt
  7z.exe l "%%A" |Findstr "^2018-03-05" >> listing.txt
)
```

The `-r` is not for listing but for adding/updating recursing folders in source

**Edit** here a version with specified `From/Until` dates:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\24\SO_50515876.cmd
@Echo off
Set "Date-From=2018-03-01"
Set "DateUntil=2018-03-30"

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s *.7z') do (
  Echo Processing %%A >> listing.txt
  For /f "tokens=1*" %%B in (
    '7z.exe l "%%A" ^|Findstr "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]"'
  ) Do (Echo %%B
    If %%B geq %Date-From% If %%B leq %DateUntil% Echo=%%B %%C >>listing.txt
  )
)
```

Sample output:

```
> type listing.txt
Processing C:\test\test.7z
2018-03-29 15:37:15 D....            0            0  subdir0
2018-03-29 15:37:15 D....            0            0  subdir1
2018-03-29 15:41:55 D....            0            0  subdir2
2018-03-29 15:37:15 D....            0            0  subdir3
2018-03-29 17:45:42 ....A          355               SelectedFolders.zip
2018-03-29 15:38:19 ....A           27               subdir.csv
2018-03-29 15:41:34 ....A           25               subdir2\20180329154134,19.txt
2018-03-29 15:42:05 ....A           25               subdir4\20180329154205,27.txt
2018-03-29 15:42:11 ....A           25               subdir4\20180329154211,87.txt
```

Comment: Thanks this helps also instead for a specific date if we need the files for a certain tenure like before or equal to year 2017. Do we need to use any date argument for that like /D +01/01/2017 ?

Comment: @PriyankaSingh, the `FINDSTR` command is just like it sounds.  It finds STRINGS of characters.  If you looked at the help file for the `FINDSTR` command you may notice that the `/D` option has nothing to do with any type of date argument.

Comment: See updated answer for a range of dates to compare. BTW the best thank would be a check mark as answer and/or a vote up.